# Is there a reason some functions don't take a void*?

Tags: c++, posix, higher-order-functions

Many functions accept a function pointer as an argument.  `atexit` and `call_once` are excellent examples.  If these higher level functions accepted a void* argument, such as `atexit(&myFunction, &argumentForMyFunction)`, then I could easily wrap any functor I pleased by passing a function pointer and a block of data to provide statefulness.

As is, there are many cases where I wish I could register a callback with arguments, but the registration function does not allow me to pass any arguments through.  `atexit` only accepts one argument: a function taking 0 arguments.  I cannot register a function to clean up after my object, I must register a function which cleans up after all objects of a class, and force my class to maintain a list of all objects needing cleanup.

I always viewed this as an oversight, there seemed no valid reason why you wouldn't allow a measly 4 or 8 byte pointer to be passed along, unless you were on an extremely limited microcontroller.  I always assumed they simply didn't realize how important that extra argument could be until it was too late to redefine the spec.  In the case of `call_once`, the posix version accepts no arguments, but the C++11 version accepts a functor (which is virtually equivalent to passing a function and an argument, only the compiler does some of the work for you).

Is there any reason why one would choose not to allow that extra argument?  Is there an advantage to accepting only "void functions with 0 arguments"?

Comment: In cases like `atexit` where you're working with global state, there is no shame in simply writing your own handler that dispatches to whichever functor or list of functors you like.  You can use a global variable to store that functor or list of functors and it doesn't really make your program any more icky.  So, for `atexit`, the answer is that there's no point.

Comment: `std::call_once` takes an arbitrary function object and an arbitrary number of arguments. As to `atexit()`, given the limited number of callbacks it's guaranteed to support, I'm not sure "register a function for every object created" is a great idea (although your basic question remains sound).

Comment: I agree that pretty much any API that takes a callback function should provide for a way to pass context to that callback (in C the usual way is via a `void*`).  I'm not sure what what your question is though - those functions don't have it so if you need to use those functions you are left with coming up with some workaround.  Is the lack of some context parameter an oversight on the part of whoever designed those interfaces?  Yeah, it probably is. In the specific case of `atexit()` you might want to consider `on_exit()` unless POSIX compliance is a hard requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I think `atexit` is just a special case, because whatever function you pass to it is supposed to be called only once. Therefore whatever state it needs to do its job can just be kept in global variables. If `atexit` were being designed today, it would probably take a `void*` in order to enable you to avoid using global variables, but that wouldn't actually give it any new functionality; it would just make the code slightly cleaner in some cases.

For many APIs, though, callbacks are allowed to take additional arguments, and not allowing them to do so would be a severe design flaw. For example, `pthread_create` does let you pass a `void*`, which makes sense because otherwise you'd need a separate function for each thread, and it would be totally impossible to write a program that spawns a variable number of threads.

Answer (score 0):

Quite a number of the interfaces taking function pointers lacking a pass-through argument are simply coming from a different time. However, their signatures can't be changed without breaking existing code. It is sort of a misdesign but that's easy to say in hindsight. The overall programming style has moved on to have limited uses of functional programming within generally non-functional programming languages. Also, at the time many of these interfaces were created storing any extra data even on "normal" computers implied an observable extra cost: aside from the extra storage used, the extra argument also needs to be passed even when it isn't used. Sure, `atexit()` is hardly bound to be a performance bottleneck seeing that it is called just once but if you'd pass an extra pointer everywhere you'd surely also have one `qsort()`'s comparison function.

Specifically for something like `atexit()` it is reasonably straight forward to use a custom global object with which function objects to be invoked upon exit are registered: just register a function with `atexit()` calling all of the functions registered with said global object. Also note that `atexit()` is only guaranteed to register up to 32 functions although implementations may support more registered functions. It seems ill-advised to use it as a registry for object clean-up function rather than the function which calling an object clean-up function as other libraries may have a need to register functions, too.

That said, I can't imagine why `atexit()` is particular useful in C++ where objects are automatically destroyed upon program termination anyway. Of course, this approach assumes that all objects are somehow held but that's normally necessary anyway in some form or the other and typically done using appropriate [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) objects.